# Does the vector space of differences of quantile functions have a neat characterization?

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-cone, total-variation, quantile-function

Consider the convex cone of quantile functions of random variables on the real line (with finite second moment), that is
$$
C := \{ Q_{\mu}: \mu \in \mathcal P_{(2)}(\mathbb R) \},
$$
where $Q_{\mu}(p) := \min\{ x: \mu((-\infty, x]) \ge p \}$, $p \in (0, 1)$ is the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#General_distribution_function) of $\mu$.
We interpret $C$ as a subset of the [square-integrable functions $\mathcal L^2((0, 1))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals) and consequently endow it with the $L^2$-norm.

For $f \colon (0, 1) \to \mathbb R$ we have $f \in C$ if and only if $f$ is non-decreasing and left-continuous (see e.g. section 1.1. of [*Random variables, monotone relations, and convex analysis* by Rockafellar and Royset](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-014-0801-1)).

The [smallest vector space containing $C$ is $\text{span}(C) = C - C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone#Properties), the space of differences of quantile functions.

> I've read that the [space of differences of non-decreasing bounded functions on a compact interval is equal to the space of functions of bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation), $\text{BV}$.
> Is there a similar characterization of $C - C$?

The difference here is that $Q_{\mu}$ is defined on a open interval and might be unbounded, e.g. if $\mu$ is a normal distribution.